# PHP: Undefined index error even the program work well

Tags: php, date, indexing, undefined

I got trouble about date format. I dont know why, let's check the code.

```
<?php
                    
                    /* date settings */
                    $month = (int) ($_GET['month'] ? $_GET['month'] : date('m'));
                    $year = (int)  ($_GET['year'] ? $_GET['year'] : date('Y'));

                    /* select month control */
                    $select_month_control = '<select name="month" id="month">';
                    for($x = 1; $x <= 12; $x++) {
                        $select_month_control.= '<option value="'.$x.'"'.($x != $month ? '' : ' selected="selected"').'>'.date('F',mktime(0,0,0,$x,1,$year)).'</option>';
                    }
                    $select_month_control.= '</select>';

                    /* select year control */
                    $year_range = 7;
                    $select_year_control = '<select name="year" id="year">';
                    for($x = ($year-floor($year_range/2)); $x <= ($year+floor($year_range/2)); $x++) {
                        $select_year_control.= '<option value="'.$x.'"'.($x != $year ? '' : ' selected="selected"').'>'.$x.'</option>';
                    }
                    $select_year_control.= '</select>';

                    /* "next month" control */
                    $next_month_link = '<a href="?month='.($month != 12 ? $month + 1 : 1).'&year='.($month != 12 ? $year : $year + 1).'" class="control">Next Month &gt;&gt;</a>';

                    /* "previous month" control */
                    $previous_month_link = '<a href="?month='.($month != 1 ? $month - 1 : 12).'&year='.($month != 1 ? $year : $year - 1).'" class="control">&lt;&lt;    Previous Month</a>';


                    /* bringing the controls together */
                    $controls = '<form method="get">'.$select_month_control.$select_year_control.'&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$previous_month_link.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$next_month_link.' </form>';

                    /* get all events for the given month */
                    $events = array();
                    $query = mysql_query("SELECT nama_task, DATE_FORMAT(tanggal_deadline,'%Y-%m-%d') AS tanggal_deadline FROM `task`");
                    if($query){
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                        $events[$row['tanggal_deadline']][] = $row;
                    }
                    }else{
                        echo 'querynya kosong';
                    }

                    echo '<h2 style="float:left; padding-right:30px;">'.date('F',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year)).' '.$year.'</h2>';
                    echo '<div style="float:left;">'.$controls.'</div>';
                    echo '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';
                    echo draw_calendar($month,$year,$events);
                    echo '<br /><br />';
                ?>
```

the calender work well, but there error message that said like this

> Notice: Undefined index: month in E:\xampp\htdocs\reminder\calendar.php on line 199
>
> Notice: Undefined index: year in E:\xampp\htdocs\reminder\calendar.php on line 200

error message said error at this line

```
$month = (int) ($_GET['month'] ? $_GET['month'] : date('m'));
$year = (int)  ($_GET['year'] ? $_GET['year'] : date('Y'));
```

thanks for take your time to read my question and my bad english.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid the message you can use [`isset`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) on the indices that may not exist

```
$month = (int) (isset($_GET['month']) ? $_GET['month'] : date('m'));
$year = (int)  (isset($_GET['year']) ? $_GET['year'] : date('Y'));
```

---

You can also use [`empty`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) in case fields are there but doesn't have any data.

```
$month = (int) (!empty($_GET['month']) ? $_GET['month'] : date('m'));
$year = (int)  (!empty($_GET['year']) ? $_GET['year'] : date('Y'));
```

Comment: But `isset()` will return true if the variable `$_GET['month']` is set and empty... here he has to do a double validation like `isset($_GET['month']) && !empty($_GET['month'])`

Comment: @MaveRick that's a bit belt and braces - empty will evaluate if the variable has been set as well, you don't need both isset() and empty() - just empty() would suffice.

Comment: @MaveRick if you're going to use empty, then you wouldn't need isset.

Comment: yes you just have to check !empty($_GET['month']) and it will help

Comment: I wouldn't say it's "avoiding the message" - sounds like error suppression ... more "avoiding the logical pitfall of evaluating an undeclared variable" (or index in this case) - just sayin' ;)

Comment: I've try to use isset, but when I put the semicolon "}" at the last line, my code does't work. I mean there aren't output in the browser.

Comment: @RezpaAditya What? Any way isset wouldn't cause any problems see http://codepad.org/tvimkz0Z

Comment: yeah, thx for you help @Musa, I used !empty like your example above and it's work. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Check Out this code I've done diting for you. 
[click here](http://www.codejaw.com/2e96tyd)